# Java reading file txt from URL

Tags: java, file, url, text, stream

I would read txt content from web, I know how to read a local file but I want to put my txt file in a website and read it in my application. I used this code :

```
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader((new URL("MY TXT    URL")).openStream()));

    String line = reader.readLine();

    int k =0;

    String[] SaveLine = new String[20];

    for( k = 0; line!=null; k++)
    {
        System.out.println(reader.readLine());

        line=reader.readLine();

    }
```

There is a problem, with this code I read the entire webpage, so the HTML is included. How can I just read the file content ? There is a specified website where I could put my txt files for read them?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

If this `"MY TXT    URL"` is indeed your TXT file's URL
(for example `http://www.test.com/file10.txt`), then your
code will read the TXT file itself, and not any web page (as you say it does).

So you're mixing something here.

Whatever URL you give to it, that web resource (file) it is going to read.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very confusing problem. Try this. Make the URL include the location and name of the textfile; here is an example: www.yourwebsiteurl.com/yourtextfile.txt. Using that method, ONLY the textfile, not including HTML, will be read.

Answer (score 0):

If the endpoint of your URL is a text file, if shouldn't be displaying any html (unless that's what's contained in your text file.)

allegedly [uploadedit](http://uploadedit.com) works though I haven't used it myself.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all, I tested my code in a txt uploaded on DropBox and Dropbox probably has code system that I don't know, infact my code returns html/script and not the content of txt. So probably the correct ask is if anybody know a website where can I put my txt file just to reading it? (the url must don't change for ever)

EDIT: PROBLEM SOLVED
I put my file in a website to just read the file and don't read it in a html box (such as a lot of cloud website)